# Expandable Floating Action button in bottom navigation bar - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to implement the below design

[image]

When I add the expandable floating button to the notch in bottom navigation bar it break the design of bottom navigation bar.

[image]

I tried AnchorOverlay but didn't help. Below is the code of my main screen where the expandable widget is notched in the bottom app bar

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
      floatingActionButton: ExpandableFab(
        distance: 112.0,
        children: [
          ActionButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(Icons.format_size),
          ),
          ActionButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(Icons.insert_photo),
          ),
          ActionButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(Icons.videocam),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        //bottom navigation bar on scaffold
        color: Colors.redAccent,
        shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(), //shape of notch
        notchMargin:
            5, //notche margin between floating button and bottom appbar
        child: Row(
          //children inside bottom appbar
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
           //IconButtons
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.menu,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.print,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.people,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I think you can try with general `CircularNotchedRectangle`  and overlay widget.

Comment: Have you found any widget or package for first pattern?

Answer (score -1):

Please refer this https://codewithandrea.com/articles/adding-animated-overlays-to-your-app/ maybe your issue will fixed.

Comment: I tried the overlay code, when I put my expandable menu in it, it throws error  'RenderBox was not laid out'

Comment: can you please share your code after changes, so try to solve error.